# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice error?

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, spring-aop

I am trying to use the spring AOP framework.  The code compiled without error.
When I tried to run it, I got the above exception.  I am using netbeans IDE 8.0.1.
I have the following libraries and jar files included.

```
1) Spring Framework 4.0.1
2) aspectjrt.jar
3) aspectjweaver.jar
4) aopalliance-alpha1.jar
5) asm-5.03.jar
6) cglib-3.1.jar
```

Here is my spring.xml config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
">

  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean name="triangle" class="springaop.Triangle">
        <property name="name" value="My Triangle" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="circle" class="springaop.Circle">
        <property name="name" value="My Circle" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="shapeService" class="springaop.ShapeService" autowire="byName" >
    </bean>

    <bean name="loginAspect" class="springaop.LoginAspect" />

</beans>
```

These are the latest jar files that are available from each publisher.
I did not see the Advice class anywhere in the aopalliance jar.  I searched for this problem.  It appears that the Advice class may have been removed from the aopalliance jar.  I have not been able to search it.   Does anyone know how to resolve  this problem other than telling me to use Maven :) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what `aopalliance-alpha1` is. You need `aopalliance` which is at version 1.0. You can get it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0). (Download JAR if you aren't using Maven.)

Comment: I got that jar file from the aopalliance website.  I could not find the aopalliance file.  The link that you provided points to aopalliance-alpha1.

Comment: @tadpole What do you mean it points to aopalliance-alpha1? There's a `Download (JAR)` link. Use that.

Comment: Ok.  I got wrong link.  I followed that link from appliance.sourceforge.net instead of just the artifact file.   Thank you.

Comment: just got saved by this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as I had added aopalliance-alpha1.jar instead of aopalliance.jar. I added the correct jar and it started working .

Answer (score -2):

I also got the same error in my eclipse env.

Cause : For working on spring aop examples, from the net I downloaded the files 'aopalliance-.jar.zip', 'aspectj-1.6.9.jar.zip', 'aspectjrt.jar.zip', 'aspectj-weaver.jar.zip' and included it directly in the java build path. The mistake I did here was I didn't extract the jar files from the zip file, instead directly added the .jar.zip file into the java build path.

Fix : Extract the jar files from above mentioned .jar.zip files and in the eclipse point to the jar files instead of zip files, then it will start working.